# how to select a part of the text from a log and add it to the beginning?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

please can someone clarify to me what would be the best way to take some text from a log line and insert it in front of the line in python.

Ex.
Input

```
<02>Jan  1 00:12:08 15.27.05.42 1,2017/09/07 00:12:08,......
```

Output

```
15.27.05.42,<02>Jan  1 00:12:08 15.27.05.42 1,2017/09/07 00:12:08,......
```

many thanks

Comment: it's unclear where does this `15.27.05.42,` come from?

Comment: Hi RomanPerekhrest, the ip number comes from the firewall that sends its log.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [re](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html) module.
If the pattern you want to prepend is unique, then it will be something like:

```
import re
in_ = "<02>Jan  1 00:12:08 15.27.05.42 1,2017/09/07 00:12:08"
pattern = re.compile(r'\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+')
res = re.search(pattern, in_)
if res:
    out_ = "{},{}".format(res.group(), in_)

# '15.27.05.42,<02>Jan  1 00:12:08 15.27.05.42 1,2017/09/07 00:12:08'
```

Comment: thank you so much for the help. I think that unfortunately the log can have a different pattern. At least as far as the ip goes, that shouldn't change.

Answer (score 0):

For 2 strings to connect  "+" operator is good enough, but for 3 or more parts strings I recomend using join() method:

```
log = "02>Jan  1 00:12:08 15.27.05.42 1,2017/09/07 00:12:08"

log = "5.27.05.42," + log
```

or

```
log = "".join("5.27.05.42," + log)
```

About exporting log into string there are many methods, all depends on what form and where you have wrriten log.

Also as @RomanPerekhrest mentions, it is unclear what you want to put before log, if it is something inside log, you will have to use regular expressions.

Comment: Thanks for the information. I wonder if, in case I have to use regular expressions, just writing the starting pattern will be enough. I say this mostly because some of the following in the log can vary

Answer (score 0):

You should first split text with `.split(" ")` then you your log file will converted to list then you can use `log_elements[index]+log` to concate them together.

Comment: thank you for your input. I will study in more detail what he says to me.